# Prove that there is $Z_\infty$ that satisfies $ \lim_{ n \to \infty } E[|Z_\infty -Z_n|^2] = 0$

Tags: probability-theory

There are iid random variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$, following $N(0,1)$.

With these variables and a constant value $a \gt 0$, we define random variables $Y_i$ and $Z_i$as
$$Y_n=aY_{n-1}+X_n $$
$$Z_n=Y_n/a^n \quad n=1,2,...$$

while $Y_0=0$.

I need to prove that there is $Z_\infty$ $(Z_\infty=L^2-\displaystyle\lim_{ n \to \infty }Z_n)$ that satisfies $$\displaystyle \lim_{ n \to \infty } E[|Z_\infty -Z_n|^2] = 0$$

Can anyone help me?

---

What I have tried

I have find a distribution of $Z_n$ by this.
$$Y_n = a^{n-1}X_1+a^{n-2}X_2+\cdots+aX_{n-1}+X_n$$
$$Z_n=\frac{Y_n}{a^n}=\frac{1}{a}X_1+\frac{1}{a^2}X_2+\cdots+\frac{1}{a^{n-1}}X_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a^n}X_n$$
$$Z_n \sim N\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a^i},n\right)$$

If this is correct, a variance of $Z_\infty$ goes to $\infty$, then I got stuck.

Comment: Note it should be $$Z_n \sim N\left(0, \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a^{2i}}\right)$$ so the variance doesn't go to $\infty$ unless $a \leq 1$, but I don't know how this might help.  It just shows that if $a > 1$, then $Z_n \Rightarrow Z_\infty \sim N\left(0, \frac{1}{a^2-1}\right)$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you for the comment. Why is $Z_n$ like that?

Comment: As long as you accept $Z_n$ is normal, the mean and variance follow from applying $$E[aX+bY] = aE[X] + bE[Y] \\ X,Y \text{ independent } \implies \operatorname{Var}[aX+bY] = a^2\operatorname{Var}[X] + b^2\operatorname{Var}[Y]$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oh I have made a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: In any case your approach will only show that $Z_n$ converges in distribution, which is not sufficient to show that it converges in $L^2$. I would probably try to show that the sequence is Cauchy in $L^2$ i.e. that $\mathbb{E}[|Z_n - Z_m|^2] \rightarrow 0$ for $n,m \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: $(Z_n)$ is a martingale.  It is $L^2$ bounded if and only if $a>1$.  Only in this case will you get $L^2$ convergence.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Ok I'll try this method first.